# SpriteKit で背景に設定した画像が表示されません

Tags: swift, spritekit

いつもお世話になっております。
SKSceneの背景を表示したいのですが、何故か？真っ黒のままになってしまいます。
翔泳社から出ている「SpriteKitではじめる2Dゲームプログラミング」と同じコードなのですが、
どこがいけなんでしょうか？
お解りになる方、教えていただけますか？

下記がコードです。

GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let backGround = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"haikei.png")
        backGround.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 0.5)
        backGround.size = self.size
        self.addChild(backGround)
    }
}
```

GameViewController.swift

```
import UIKit import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = GameScene()
        let view = self.view as! SKView
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
        scene.size = view.frame.size

        view.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Comment: あなたのコードをそのままコピペしてプロジェクトを実行してみましたが、普通にhaikei.pngの内容が表示されました。あちこち間違えそうなところをいじってみましたが「真っ黒な画面」は再現できませんでした。まさかhaikei.pngが真っ黒な画像だとかいうことはないですよね。その他haikei.pngがビルドターゲットに含まれているか、Main.storyboardの設定は正しいか(特にEntry PointになっているViewControllerやViewのCustom Class)、またXcodeから実行した時に何かしらのエラーや警告がデバッグコンソールに出力されていないかなど確認してみてください。

Comment: アドバイスいただき有難うございます。原因がようやく掴めました。pngのサイズが大き過ぎて表示できなかったようです。サイズを小さくしたところ、キチンと表示できました。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。そう言うこともあるのですね。こちらもまだまだ経験を積まないといけないようです。

Comment: とんでもありません。私もキチンと確認してから質問するべきでした。これに懲りずにアドバイスお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

原因がようやく掴めました。png 画像のサイズが大き過ぎて表示できなかったようです。
サイズを小さくしたところ、キチンと表示できました。

---

*この投稿は @woodpecker さんのコメント の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*